# Rendering the component without <Outlet /> React Route v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Is there any way to render the entire component by `<Route \>` that is nested, bypassing the parent component's `<Outlet \>`?

App.js

```
<Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />}>
  <Route index element={<ProfileDetails />} />
  <Route path="offer" element={<MyJobs />}>
    <Route path="add" element={<AddJob />} /> // <-- This component to render whole without parent components
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Profile.js

```
const Profile = () => {
  return(
    ....
      <Outlet />
    ....
  );
};
```

AddJob.js

```
const AddJob = () => {
  return <h2>text</h2>;
};

export default AddJob;
```

Is it possible to make only this component render `AddJob`? I don't want it to render as `<Outlet />` in `Profile.js`

Answer (score 1):

If you want `AddJob` to render alone on its route then its route will need to be unnested from the route rendering the `Profile` layout route component.

Example:

```
<Route path="/profile">
  <Route element={<Profile />}>
    <Route index element={<ProfileDetails />} />
    <Route path="offer" element={<MyJobs />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="offer/add" element={<AddJob />} />
</Route>
```

[image: Edit rendering-the-component-without-outlet-react-route-v6]